# I am using Android Studio, the lastest one however when I try to drag and drop the text or button or anything it doesn't show up on the blueprint

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-3.1

I have had a look to see if the problem can be solved but I cannot find anything. I have a couple of errors shown below.

[An image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utqY8.png)[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGim6.png)[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6Ah1.png)[Error 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VsiD.png)[Error 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLEH0.png)[Error 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcRHo.png)

Comment: Try to change height and width attributes of what ever view you are tryring to add.

Comment: Which version of Android Studio are you running? Your question tag says 3.0. If that's your version, you can try updating to the latest, which is 3.1.3.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could expand those shown errors. They may provide more specific insight into the issues.

Comment: Ok i will add in the errors, I am already on the lastest 3.1.3 android studio

Comment: I have attached all the different errors